# Why do I get the same dataframe returned after dropping rows?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

Why can't i drop these rows?

```
# drop rows from the first dataframe
droprows = list(range(4))
tables[0].drop(axis = 0, index = droprows)
#help(tables[0])
tables[0]
```

the output is exactly the same as before i drop the columns.

```
    Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2  Unnamed: 3  Unnamed: 4  Unnamed: 5  Net Hydro-
0   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN Mean    NaN NaN
1   No. NaN Sequence    RFU 1   RFU 2   NaN charge  pathy
2   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN RFU NaN NaN
3   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN pH 7.4  score
4   1   YRFK    NaN 1.82    1.82    1.82    2   1.2
5   2   RRRRR   NaN 7.53    7.19    7.36    5   15.0
6   3   VPMLK   NaN 1.96    2.15    2.05    1   -1.6
7   4   VPTLK   NaN -0.25   -1.17   -0.71   1   -0.7
8   5   VPALR   NaN 3.43    3.52    3.48    1   -0.8
9   6   VSALK   NaN 2.70    0.05    1.38    1   -0.5
```

Does this have anything to do with the data types of my objects?

```
print(type(tables))
type(tables[0])
```

output:

```
<class 'list'>
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

Comment: `drop` returns a copy, Either do `table[0] = table[0].drop...` or pass `inplace=True` to `drop`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your "drop" function equal to your table, like this.

`table = tables[0].drop(axis = 0, index = droprows)`

I would also recommend more explicitly refering to the column that you would like to drop. Specifically, changing:

`tables[0]` to `tables['Unnamed: 0']`